# disabled app and app_dev.php on my server prod Symfony 2.3

Tags: apache, symfony

I move my project to my server and I do not want that app and app_dev and all dev environments are available

It would be even better if I could filter out the ip that have permission to access the server prod in dev environment (app_dev.php)

I have to change apache or Symfony?
Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you can open app.php or app_dev.php because when you ask something like this, i can't believe you already have open these files once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dev env should only be accessed on the server where you are developing. That said, you could do it in Apache, but Symfony does it for you automatically.

From app_dev.php:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Just add the IPs you want to be able to access from in the array.